# How to get per typoscript the URL of video in tx_news (tab relations)?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, tx-news

1. I have created a new item in tx_news.
2. I added in this item one media-file (in tab-relation) as media-url-youtube.
3. I would like to get per typoscript the url of this youtube-video.

if I add on Step 2 one picture-file (rather than media-file-url), I can get picture-url with code below

```
page.headerData.87 >
page.headerData.87 = COA

page.headerData.87.1 = COA
page.headerData.87.1.1 = TEXT
page.headerData.87.1.1.value = <meta property="og:image"             
content="http://www.MyHomePage.com/
page.headerData.87.1.2 =COA
page.headerData.87.1.2 {

5=RECORDS
5 {


  dontCheckPid = 1
  tables = tx_news_domain_model_news
  source.data = GP:tx_news_pi1|news
  source.intval = 1
  conf.tx_news_domain_model_news = FILES
  conf.tx_news_domain_model_news {
    references {
      table = tx_news_domain_model_news
      fieldName = fal_media
      uid.field = uid
    }
    begin = 0
    maxItems = 1
    renderObj = IMG_RESOURCE
    renderObj.file {
      maxW = 1200
      import.data = file:current:publicUrl
      treatIdAsReference = 1
    }
  }




}
}
page.headerData.87.1.3 = TEXT
page.headerData.87.1.3.value = " />
```

But it not working, if in Step 2 Youtube-Video added.

How should I change my typoscript to achive this goal?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED

```
temp.videofilename = COA
temp.videofilename.1 = TEXT
temp.videofilename.1.value = fileadmin

temp.videofilename.2 = CONTENT
temp.videofilename.2 {
    if.isTrue.data = GP:tx_news_pi1|news
    table = tx_news_domain_model_news
    select {
        uidInList.data = GP:tx_news_pi1|news
        pidInList = 87
        # 87 is a folder with Your News
        join = sys_file_reference ON tx_news_domain_model_news.uid = sys_file_reference.uid_foreign JOIN sys_file ON sys_file.uid = sys_file_reference.uid_local
        where sys_file.mime_type = 'video/youtube' AND sys_file_reference.deleted = 0
        orderBy = sys_file_reference.sorting
        max = 1
    }
    renderObj = TEXT
    renderObj {
        field = identifier
    }
}

page.headerData.89.85 = COA
page.headerData.89.85.1 = TEXT
page.headerData.89.85.1.value = <meta property="og:video" content="https://youtu.be/
page.headerData.89.85.2 =COA
page.headerData.89.85.2 {
5 = FILE
5.file.cObject < temp.videofilename
}
page.headerData.89.85.3 = TEXT
page.headerData.89.85.3.value = " />
```